# I have a question about java polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

Why is the final output "WuffRingding" instead of "RingdingRingding"?

```
package ubung;


 class Hund{
    public Hund(){
    }

    public String bellen(){
        return "Wuff";
    }

    public String spielen(Hund h){
        return "Wuff" + h.bellen();
    }


}

class Fuchs extends Hund{

    public Fuchs(){

    }

    public String bellen(){
        return "Ringding";
    }

    public String spielen(Fuchs f){
        return "Ringding"+ f.bellen();
    }

}



public class park {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Hund bello = new Hund();
        Fuchs foxi = new Fuchs();
        Hund hybrid = new Fuchs();

        System.out.println(hybrid.spielen(foxi));


    }
}
```

Why is the final output "WuffRingding" instead of "RingdingRingding"?
Why is the final output "WuffRingding" instead of "RingdingRingding"?

Comment: Can you translate this code to English to make it more readable for others?

Comment: Possibly related: [Java Static and Dynamic Binding, Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34866199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is `WuffRingding` since the method `public String spielen(Hund h)` is ***overloaded*** in the child class `Fuchs` to `public String spielen(Fuchs f)`. 
Java calls the method of the type and not of the actual instance when a method is overloaded.

So the type used here is `Hund` for the `hybrid` variable and since the method to be called is decided at compile time for overloaded methods the overloaded method of the `Hund` class is invoked althogh it is pointing to the `Fuchs` instance.

Now you supplied a instance of `Fuchs` as a parameter to the `spielen(Hund h)` which clearly takes the type `Hund` as a parameter, this worked as `Hund` is a parent of `Fuchs` and can hold `Fuchs` reference, this combined with runtime/dynamic polymorphism the `bellen` method of the `Fuchs` class is called instead of `Hund` as at runtime the type of the instance is inspected and it was actually pointing to an instance of `Fuchs`.

**TLDR;**

- Invoked `spielen` on a `Hund` reference, calls `spielen` of `Hund` class as it is overloaded.
- Passed an instance of `Fuchs` so at runtime the method `bellen` of `Fuchs` is called instead of `Hund` due to *dynamic method dispatch / runtime polymorphism*.

Comment: @Code_Mode if you see the parameter types of `spielen` is different in the parent and child class so yes they are overloaded.

Comment: @Code_Mode still it will be overloading as parameter type is different, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439649/why-are-contravariant-parameter-types-in-java-not-allowed-for-overriding

Comment: Yes..My bad. I was considering covariant return type

Comment: @Code_Mode no problem buddy!