# Dynamic Binding java test

Tags: java, polymorphism, dynamic-binding

Doing this java exercise I can't figure out why the last line print out "5".

```
public class Customer { }

public class RegisteredCustomer extends Customer{}

public class Shop {
    public int computeDiscount(Customer c){return 0;}
}

public class OnlineShop extends Shop {
    public int computeDiscount(Customer c){return 5;}
    public int computeDiscount(RegisteredCustomer c){return 15;}
}


public class OnlinePremiumShop extends OnlineShop{
    public int computeDiscount(RegisteredCustomer c){return 20+super.computeDiscount(c);}
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
        RegisteredCustomer c3 = new RegisteredCustomer();
        Shop s2 = new OnlinePremiumShop();
        System.out.println(s2.computeDiscount(c3));
}
```

Why java catch the method with Customer parameter, if c3 is both dynamic and static type RegisteredCustomer? I think I'm getting confused by binding..what's the process of thinking to not get wrong?

Comment: Please show the `main()` method that drives this example.

Comment: `s2` is variable of type `Shop` which has only one method `computeDiscount(Customer c)` so only this method is possible to be picked when calling `s2.computeDiscount(c3)`. What other thing you expected to happen? Why?

Comment: Possibly related: [Java Static and Dynamic Binding, Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34866199)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Shop s2 = new OnlinePremiumShop();
```

Here you create an `OnlinePremiumShop` object and assign it to a reference of type `Shop`. In `Shop`, the only method declared is:

```
    public int computeDiscount(Customer c){return 0;}
```

So when you call `s2.computeDiscount()`, you MUST call the one that takes a `Customer` parameter. Since the concrete type `OnlinePremiumShop` overrides this method, that is the one that is called and the result is `5`.

`s2` doesn't know about any version of `computeDsicount()` that takes a `RegisteredCustomer` parameter, so it is unable to bind to that version in the child class.