# Java class inheritance how does the compiler know which method needs to be used

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

Can someone explain how does the compiler works out which method he should take

```
class All { /* ... */ }
class Most extends All { /* ... */ }
class Special extends Most { /* ... */ }

class Top {
    public void m( All p ) { System.out.print("A "); }
}

class Middle extends Top {
    public void m( All p ) { System.out.print("M "); }
    public void m( Special p ) { System.out.print("L "); }
}

class Bottom extends Middle {
    public void m( Most p ) { System.out.print("V "); }
    public void m( Special p ) { System.out.print("X "); }
}

class Test {
    public static void run() {

        All all = new All();
        Most most = new Most();
        Special special = new Special();
    
        Top x = new Middle();
        Top y = new Bottom();
        Middle z = new Bottom();
    
        x.m( most );
        x.m( special );
        y.m( all );
        y.m( special );
        z.m( all );
        z.m( most );
    }
}
```

For example you see a class inheritance of `top`, `middle` and `bottom`  and `all`, `most` and `special` in this code. If I run this I get the output of `M M M M M M`.

I need to know why the compiler always takes the method m() of the middle class.

Why `x.M(special)` doesn't print out L?
Why does `y.M(all)` and `y.M(special)` print out M again?

Comment: Possibly related: [Java Static and Dynamic Binding, Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34866199)

Answer (score 6):

There are two aspects involved here:

- *Overloading*, which occurs at compile-time, and which selects the appropriate method *signature* based on the compile-time method target and arguments
- *Overriding*, which occurs at execution-time, and which selects the *implementation* of the method (with the compile-time-selected signature) based on the execution-time type of the object.

In your specific example, `x.m(special)` needs to resolve a call with a target type of `Top` (the *compile-time* type of `x`) and an argument of `Special` (the compile-time type of `special`).

There's only one method called `m` in `Top`, and that's `m(All)`, so that's what the compiler selects (after validating that there's an implicit conversion from `Special` to `All`). At execution time, the type of the object that `x` refers to is `Middle`, so it executes the implementation of `m(All)` in `Middle`. Likewise the compile-time type of `y` is `Top`, so the `m(All)` signature is picked, and it doesn't matter that `y` is actually an instance of `Bottom`, because `Bottom` doesn't override `m(All)`.